# Difference from returning in a promise and outside a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

In the code below. When i put the `return true` in the `.error` or in the `.success` function. Then nothing happends.

But when I put it outside my `.error` or `.success` function then it returns nicely and it closes my `ngDialog` when i `return true`. However I don't really understand why.

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('NewUserController',function($scope, User, $http){

    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.save = function()
    {
        User.create($scope.user)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log('success');
                return true;
            })
            .error(function(data){
                console.log('error')
                return false;
            });

        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: because in that case when you returning in success it not returning because it's in callback function and I think the context is not the same.

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan how can I make it returning success from the .success function?

Comment: Why you are not using promises instead of callback ?

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan not sure how to do that

Comment: Do you have other function which can close dialog ?

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan yes it's the default `closeThisDialog()` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70304/discussion-between-sanders-and-narek-mamikonyan).

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.save = function()
{
    return User.create($scope.user)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log('success');
            return true;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('error')
            return false;
        });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. My dialog stays open even in the .success function.

Comment: Could you show the part where you actually trying to close the dialog? Where do you call closeThisDialog()?